# Using fitnesse to test services based on xml over http

Tags: java, testing, automated-tests, fitnesse, fit-framework

I’m struggling to come up with a good approach to write automated acceptance tests for services based on xml over http using Fitnesse. These services have complex requests and responses with xml-elements from schemas that are not shared between services. I don’t want to create tremendous amounts of Fixture-code to build up requests, marshaling/unmarshaling and do http-invoking for each service.

I’ve looked into the RestFixture(https://github.com/smartrics/RestFixture) which seems to as a great approach to limit the plumbing effort for testing these kind of services. The only problem is generating the request in a good way. For “real” rest services this would not be a problem, but my services requires a lot of xml in the request-body.

I would like to somehow allow the tester to build up their request using a Scenario table, but since all the services uses different schemas it can’t see how I can do this without creating a really complex backing-fixture responsible for creating all the different request or several Fixtures each responsible for generating request for one service. In either case I would be back to writing expensive plumbing. 
Does anyone here have some thoughts on this?

Comment: I asked a similar question and the answer appears to be there isn't any generic fixture. You'll need to write custom fixtures to handle the XML parsing into the flat name/value pairs Fitnesse supports for it's validation. Deciding how to expose the parsed objects is a bit challenging.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Guess I should start thinking of a good way to expose the parsed objects.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a fixture to tackle this problem without any additional coding: [XmlHttpTest](https://github.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures/wiki/2.-Slim-Fixtures#xmlhttptest). Creating the request is not dealt with using (custom) Java code mimicking the XML structure. Instead it is dealt with as generating a text value where placeholders need to be replaced. Checks are performed using XPath expressions.

Sample usage (extracted from [one of the project's GitHub wiki pages](https://github.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures/wiki/4.-XmlHttpTest-Examples)) for a single call:

```
!define POST_BODY { {{{
<s11:Envelope xmlns:s11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s11:Body>
    <ns1:GetCityWeatherByZIP xmlns:ns1="http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/">
      <ns1:ZIP>90210</ns1:ZIP>
    </ns1:GetCityWeatherByZIP>
  </s11:Body>
</s11:Envelope>
}}} }

|script         |xml http test                                                       |
|post           |${POST_BODY}   |to                   |${URL}                        |
|check          |response status|200                                                 |
|show           |response                                                            |
|register prefix|weather        |for namespace        |http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/|
|check          |xPath          |//weather:City/text()|Beverly Hills                 |
```

[(Result)](http://fhoeben.github.io/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures/examples-results/HsacExamples.SlimTests.HttpTests.HttpPost1Test.html)

Or (using scenario to make multiple calls)

```
!*> Scenario definition
!define POST_BODY_2 { {{{
<s11:Envelope xmlns:s11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s11:Body>
    <ns1:GetCityWeatherByZIP xmlns:ns1="http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/">
      <ns1:ZIP>@{zip}</ns1:ZIP>
    </ns1:GetCityWeatherByZIP>
  </s11:Body>
</s11:Envelope>
}}} }

|script|xml http test|

|table template |send request                                                        |
|post           |${POST_BODY_2} |to                   |${URL}                        |
|check          |response status|200                                                 |
|show           |response                                                            |
|register prefix|weather        |for namespace        |http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/|
|check          |xPath          |//weather:City/text()|@{City}                       |
*!

|send request       |
|zip  |City         |
|10007|New York     |
|94102|San Francisco|
```

([Result](http://fhoeben.github.io/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures/examples-results/HsacExamples.SlimTests.HttpTests.HttpPost2UsingScenarioTest.html))

For more complex requests the [fixture also allows the usage of a Freemarker template](http://fhoeben.github.io/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures/examples-results/HsacExamples.SlimTests.HttpTests.HttpPost3UsingFreemarkerTemplateTest.html) (for things like optional elements and iteration).